# How to bind Stacklayout with MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to bind my Stacklayout's items using Viewmodel i have already declared all the variables and properties and all within my view model so i am mentioning here my code please tell how i'll do this.

This is my XAML Code:

```
<controls:OffersListView ImageGIF="outlet" BImage="{Binding BannerUri}"/>
```

And this is my OffersListView.xaml code

```
<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage  x:Name="imageFront"                 
                              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                   
                              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                              Aspect="AspectFill"
                              Margin="0"
                             IsVisible="True"
                             Source="{Binding ImageGIF}"
                            LoadingPlaceholder="imageBehind"
                            Finish="ImageFront_Finish"
                            DownloadStarted="ImageFront_DownloadStarted"/>

<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage  x:Name="imageBehind" 
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                HeightRequest="205"
                                WidthRequest="350"
                                IsVisible="False"
                                Margin="0"
                                Source="{Binding BImage}"/>
```

My ViewModel Code is:

```
public int BannerId
        {
            get
            {
                return HomeItems.BannerId;
            }
            set
            {
                HomeItems.BannerId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

And here i am binding value in my Home.xamal.cs page. Scrollview contains all items which i am trying to bind using MVVM

```
private void SetItemSource()
        {
            m_homeViewModel = new ObservableCollection<HomeViewModel>();
            scrollview.BindingContext = m_homeViewModel;
        }
```

Now when i am `BImage="{Binding BannerUri}"` going to bind BannerUri using Viewmodel then it is throwing an exception the exception is:

```
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'BImage', or mismatching type between value and property.
```

This is my Offerlistview xaml code:

================================================================================

```
<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage  x:Name="imageFront" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                Margin="0"
                                                IsVisible="True"
                                                Source="{Binding ImageGIF}"
                                                LoadingPlaceholder="imageBehind"
                                                Finish="ImageFront_Finish"
                                                DownloadStarted="ImageFront_DownloadStarted"/>
                <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage  x:Name="imageBehind" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                                HeightRequest="205"
                                                WidthRequest="350"
                                                IsVisible="False"
                                                Margin="0"
                                                Source="{Binding BImage}"/>
```

===============================================================================

This is my Offerlistview.xaml.cs

================================================================================

```
 public ImageSource ImageGIF
        {
            get { return imageFront.Source; }
            set { imageFront.Source = value; }
        }

        public ImageSource BImage
        {
            get { return imageBehind.Source; }
            set { imageBehind.Source = value; }
        }
```

===============================================================================

**I think no one has it's answer**

Comment: Can you show me the `OffersListView`? I think the issue is that your `OffersListView` does not have a `BindableProperty` for the `BImage` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create bindable properties in your custom control code-behind and bind them to your inner views.

`OffersListview` code behind:

```cs
public partial class OffersListview
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageGifSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ImageGifSource),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(OffersListview));

    public static readonly BindableProperty BannerSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(BannerSource),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(OffersListview));

    public string ImageGifSource
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ImageGifSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageGifSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public string BannerSource
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(BannerSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(BannerSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

`OffersListView` xaml:

```xml
<controls:BaseClass x:Class="XXX.XXX.OffersListview"
                  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:controls:="clr-namespace:XXX.XXX"
                  x:Name="RootLayout">

    ...

    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                   
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    IsVisible="True"
                                    LoadingPlaceholder="imageBehind"
                                    Finish="ImageFront_Finish"
                                    DownloadStarted="ImageFront_DownloadStarted"
                                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference RootLayout}, Path=ImageGifSource}" />

    <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                    HeightRequest="205"
                                    WidthRequest="350"
                                    IsVisible="False"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference RootLayout}, Path=BannerSource}" />
    ...
```